# Display 3-Tier json array using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json file which I want to read using PHP, I use below code to display data till 2nd array but I don't know how to get 3rd array. Below is my php code and json file,

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$counters = $data['counters']['counters'];
foreach ($counters as $row)
{
echo $name = $row['name']."<br>";
}
```

This Above code Output is **C0**

My JSON file has the following data

```
    {
    "counters":
        {
        "id":"#F02D27B324BF41AF",
        "counterCount":14,
        "counters":[
            {
            "name":"C0",
            "total":{"request":712,"in":22982423,"out":13787213},
            "html":{"request":105,"in":2073293,"out":485846}
            },
{
            "name":"C1",
            "total":{"request":712,"in":22982423,"out":13787213},
            "html":{"request":105,"in":2073293,"out":485846}
            }]
        },
    "status":
        {
        "version":"0.0.0.2",
        "command":"getdata",
        "opf":"json",
        "error":false,
        "code":0
        }
    }
```

My Code Display me **name** which is **C0** and I want to display **data inside total and html** which is **request, in and out**

Comment: can you show some your expected sample output?

Comment: @kumar_v I update my question and I show my out put there

Comment: If you need to output json just for debug purpose you can use echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>'; to output it as php nested arrays. Or you can just output the input file content $json = file_get_contents('data.json'); echo $json;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this..

```
foreach ($counters as $row) {
    echo $name = $row['name']."<br>";
    echo $total = $row['total']['request']." ".$row['total']['in']." ".$row['total']['out']."<br>";
    echo $html = $row['html']['request']." ".$row['html']['in']." ".$row['html']['out']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I also solved it in the same way and post my answer also but I click ur answer as accepted :) thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You access it the same way as any other multidimensional array:

```
echo $name = $row['html']['request']."<br>"
```

or iterate (i.e. using `foreach()`) over it.

Comment: No, since decoding was into arrays (see second param)

Comment: true. I just looked at json

Comment: I solved it the same way you did, thank you so much for ur answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you're forgetting about top-level array. Your `[counters][counters]` is array, so you need to do like:

```
foreach($data['counters']['counters'] as $item)
{
   foreach($item as $key=>$value)
   {
      echo('<br>'.$key.' = ');
      if(is_array($value))
      {
         foreach($value as $sub=>$number)
         {
            echo($sub.':'.$number).' ';
         }
       }
      else
         echo($value);  
   }
}
```

-output will be:

```
name = C0
total = request:712 in:22982423 out:13787213
html = request:105 in:2073293 out:485846
```

Comment: I solved it but I like the way you make it more simple. I just update my array and now its C0 and C1. Can we just show 1 result instead of loop over all data.

Comment: Yes, you can then get rid of higher level loop and iterate through `$data['counters']['counters'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

you should have everything there after 
    json_decode($json,true);

try

```
foreach ($counters as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "name") {
       echo $value; // should output "C0"
    } else if ($key == "total") {
       // now the value is another array object
       echo $value["request"]; // should output 712
    } else if ($key == "html") {
       // same here
       echo $value["request"]; // should output 105
    }
}
```

i recommend to setup xdebug and jump into debugging of stuff like that, then you can inspect your $data variable and can get everything done right in the first try :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I solved it :)
To display data inside total and html, we just need to write 1 simple line,

```
$name = $row['total']['request'];
```

Its output will be **712**